# which data type is faster for cache (dictionary or dataframe)?

Tags: python

I am writing a program with a class called "Variable". Each variable will perform some calculations and stores the results in its own "cache". Currently, the "cache" is a dictionary,for example,

```
{(1,2):results_for_parameter_(1,2),
(3,4):results_for_parameter_(3,4)...etc}
```

The only usage of this cache is to read and write the results of the "cache". Reading and writing of cache will be performed quite frequently. The size of this dictionary will be quite large. It(the cache) may have more than 1 million items(I have not yet decided the complexity of my model). I am thinking of whether to change the data type of this cache to pandas.dataframe.

what I want to ask is which data type is more efficient under this scenario. More specifically, which data type should be faster to:

1. At the beginning of each loop of calculation, every values in the cache will be deleted. The basic structure of the cache will remain.
2. the model consists of hundreds of "Variable", each of them will perform a calculation, which may take values from other "Variable"(in this case, the cache of other variables will be read)
3. Each "Variable" will be calculated millions (the actual number will be decided later, maybe only 10000 in the end) of times in a single loop, using million combinations of parameters eg (1,2),(3,4)... etc
4. After all the calculations, the cache will be stored, and we go back to step 1 for another loop
5. There will be around 1000 loops of calculation

Any other considerations of using one data type over the other is also welcomed.
Thank you for your answers!
EDIT: you can also recommend any more efficient way for caches than what I have proposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will answer your question. However, it may not be what you're looking for due to my approach to the word "faster". My apologies in advance. Nonetheless, I'll try my best.

**Short answer:** DataFrame.

**Long answer:** Dictionaries and DataFrames are great for lots of things; same or different. I can't exactly prove that one is faster than the other. However, I believe I can make a strong case that DataFrames are:

1. Easier to work with
2. Have better capabilities
3. Are fast by themselves, and **really** fast with just a few tweaks and the right functions

For example, to make anything related to a DataFrame go faster, you could try loading the `Cython` extension and use a few syntax changes. You can read about this in the pandas documentation for Enhancing Performance https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html.

It can also help to  ensure you're using the right function to get what you're looking for. Examples of this include `iloc`, `loc`, `contains`, `lookup`, or `isin`.

In the end, if you want to see some data about what is faster, you'll want to `prun` some functions, or use `timeit` on some loops. In case your results show that dictionaries are faster, I would buy that answer. However, I would also be skeptical, because with the right approach to a DataFrame, it can be **really** fast.